# TabLayout: show/hide subtitle when click on a tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I'm finding pretty hard to resolve this problem.

My app has a MainActivity in which I've a TabFragment containing a TabLayout.
I want to show a subtitle in the MainActivity's Toolbar only when the user click on the second tab, and hide that when I click off of that.

I've already managed to obtain it through the side NavigationDrawer (I can select a tab from there too, and everything is working).
Still, I can't understand how to set a setOnClickListener on tabs (which are in the fragment) and then ask the container Activity to show the subtitle only if I'm in the second tab.

I've those two methods in my **MainActivity**, which I use to show/hide the subtitle.

```
// Update the petrol stations' total count.
public void updatePetrolStationsCount(Toolbar toolbar) {
    PetrolLab petrolLab = PetrolLab.get(getApplicationContext());
    int petrolStationsSize = petrolLab.getPetrolStations().size();
    String totalCount = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.total_count_format, petrolStationsSize, petrolStationsSize);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setSubtitle(totalCount);
}

// Hide the petrol stations' total count.
public void hidePetrolStationsCount(Toolbar toolbar) {
    String totalCount = null;

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setSubtitle(totalCount);
}
```

Inside of my **TabFragment**, I'm using an inner class for the TabPager.

```
class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // Return fragment with respect to position.
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment;

        switch (position) {

            case MAP_POSITION:
                fragment = MapFragment.newInstance(MAP_TYPE);
                return fragment;

            case PETROL_POSITION:
                fragment = PetrolStationListFragment.newInstance(position);
                return fragment;

            case FAV_POSITION:
                return new FavouritesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return intItems;
    }

}
```

Any hints on how I can tell the MainActivity that the user has selected the second tab in the TabFragment? Like putting a Listener on each tab. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  register  BroadCastReceive on MainActivity, send message to BroadCast  when you select the second tab 
like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //to register BroadCastReceive
    manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
     myReceive =  new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();   
    filter.addAction("com.action.changetab");//fill you want to write
    manager.registerReceiver(myReceive,filter);
}

class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          int xy= intent.getIntExtra("xy",0);
          if(xy==1){
            //change tab
          }
     }
}
```

in fragment

```
manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
Intent intent= new Intent("com.action.changetab");//same as you filter
                     intent.putExtra("xy",1);
                     manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You'd better learn BroadCast first from google ,It makes you a deeper understanding of it

Comment: Any template code about how to do that? Or a guide? Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem thanks to Cgx.

I've set up my MainActivity like he said, and then, inside of the **TabFragment**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        int flag;

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if (tab.getPosition() == PETROL_POSITION) {
                flag = 1;
                sendBroadcast(flag);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == PETROL_POSITION) {
                flag = 0;
                sendBroadcast(flag);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

    });

    return view;

}

// Send a broadcast to MainActivity about the tab we are inside to.
public void sendBroadcast(int flag) {
    mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_TAB_ID);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TAB_ID, flag);
    mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```